# C++ ternary assignment of lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, conditional-operator

Any idea why the following snippet doesn't compile? It complains with an error "error: operands to ?: have different types"

```
  auto lambda1 = [&](T& arg) {
      ...
  };
  auto lambda2 = [&](T& arg) {
      ...
  };
  auto lambda = condition ? lambda1 : lambda2;
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Individual lambdas are translated to different classes by the compiler.
For example, lambda1's definition is equivalent to:

```cpp
class SomeCompilerGeneratedTypeName {
public:
  SomeCompilerGeneratedTypeName(...) { // Capture all the required variables here
  }

  void operator()(T& arg) const {
    // ...
  }

private:
  // All the captured variables here ...
};
```

Therefore, two different types are generated by the compiler, which causes a type incompatibility for `auto lambda = condition ? lambda1 : lambda2;`

The following would work:

```cpp
auto lambda = condition ? std::function<void(T&)>(lambda1) : std::function<void(T&)>(lambda2);
```

To highlight that both lambdas are indeed different types, we can use [`<typeinfo>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) from the standard library and the `typeid` operator. Lambdas are not polymorphic types, so the standard guarantees that the 'typeid' operator is evaluated at compile time. This shows that the following example is valid even if RTTI is disabled:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    struct T {

    };

    auto lambda1 = [&](T& arg) {
        return;
    };

    auto lambda2 = [&](T& arg) {
      return;
    };

    std::cout << typeid(lambda1).name() << "/" << typeid(lambda1).hash_code() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(lambda2).name() << "/" << typeid(lambda2).hash_code() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the program is (with GCC 8.3, [see on Gobolt](https://godbolt.org/z/pwT33g)):

```
Z4mainEUlRZ4mainE1TE_/7654536205164302515
Z4mainEUlRZ4mainE1TE0_/10614161759544824066
```

Comment: Complete error is "error: operands to ?: have different types ‘f(const std::vector<int>&, size_t, size_t) [with T = unsigned char; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(unsigned char&)>’ and ‘f(const std::vector<int>&, size_t, size_t) [with T = unsigned char; size_t = long unsigned int]::<lambda(unsigned char&)>’", in which i see identical all types & formats.

Comment: @cow Because the lambda in themselves have the same signature so the compiler, in order to hide its implementation details and to give a more understandable error, gives you the location and signature of both lambdas which are identicals. But in the end, they are still interpreted as `SomeCompilerGeneratedTypeName1` and `SomeCompilerGeneratedTypeName2`

Comment: @cow i added an example that highlights the beginning of the answer, you might find it interesting

Answer (score 13):

Curiously, if lambdas are capture-less, operator `+` trick can be employed:

```
auto lambda1 = [](int arg) { ... };
auto lambda2 = [](int arg) { ... };

auto lambda = condition ? +lambda1 : +lambda2; // This compiles!
lambda(2019);
```

This works, because `+` will convert lambda into a function pointer, and both function pointers have the same type (something like `void (*)(int)`).

With GCC and Clang (but not with MSVC), `+` can be omitted, lambdas will still be converted into function pointers.

Comment: This won't work on visual studio though. Their extension that allow a lambda to convert to different calling convesion prevents it.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot, thanks for this note. Could you please give a link where I can read more about it?

Comment: [Here you go](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623)

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot It seems to compile on a recent MSVC version though. https://godbolt.org/z/ZQLWxy

Comment: @Brian Oh! This is excellent news. Now I have to change some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

The compiler can't decide what type `auto` should be:

```
auto lambda = condition ? lambda1 : lambda2;
```

since every lambda has a different and unique type.

One way that'll work is:

```
auto lambda = [&](T& arg) {
     return (condition ? lambda1(arg) : lambda2(arg));
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Since 2 lambdas(`lambda1` and `lambda2`) are 2 different types, `?:` cannot deduce return type for `lambda` from `lambda1` and `lambda2`. This happens because these 2 are not convertible to each other.

Answer (score 8):

It doesn't compile because each lambda has a unique type, there isn't a common type for `?:`.

You could wrap them in `std::function<void(T&)>`, e.g.

```
auto lamba1 = [&](T& arg) {
  ...
};
auto lambda2 = [&](T& arg) {
  ...
};
auto lambda = condition ? std::function(lambda1) : lambda2; // C++17 class template deduction
```